# Drawing a dashed line with fabric.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I'd like to draw a dashed line using fabric.js.
[I've found Issue #603 on github that should implement this feature.](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/603)
However I didn't find any example code and can't get it to work with fabric.js 1.2.1.

Is it already part of fabric.js 1.2.1 or do I have to get it off github directly and build it myself? Could someone provide me with a simple example to get me started?

Comment: You can see some examples on this test page — http://fabricjs.com/test/svg_export/stroke.html

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The property you're looking for is `strokeDashArray` which encodes the SVG attribute [`stroke-dasharray`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#StrokeDasharrayProperty). It expects an array that describes the pattern of dashes and gaps, see the linked page for more details.

An example of usage may look like the following, which would create a dashed black line with equally spaced 5px fills:

```
new fabric.Line([0, 20, 100, 20], {
    strokeDashArray: [5, 5],
    stroke: 'black'
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works just as expected.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I wish that fabric had better documentation for beginners. I LOVE the library, but I can't always determine how things need to be done.